# What is provideLayout()?.let { setContentView(it) }?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax

So I would like to learn more about cameraX, the relatively new addition to the Android Jetpack library. I've been looking at an existing project on GitHub to help me understand how to set things up. However the issue is that i'm new to kotlin (project is in kotlin).

In the project: [Project](https://github.com/arindamxd/android-camerax)

there exists something called "it"

Can be seen here: [Example](https://github.com/arindamxd/android-camerax/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/arindam/camerax/ui/base/BaseActivity.kt)

More specifically in the following line:

```
provideLayout()?.let { setContentView(it) }
```

"it" is repeated multiple times throughout the project as well. I just want to know what this is. Is "it" a variable? Is "it" Kotlin specific code?

Additionally, what is:

```
provideLayout()?.let
```

How does this work? What does it do?

**UPDATE**

Specific to CommonsWare solution (error):

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.memory.pod.debug, PID: 31521
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.memory.pod.debug/com.memory.pod.camerax.ui.home.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.memory.pod.debug:layout/activity_home: Binary XML file line #8 in com.memory.pod.debug:layout/activity_home: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.memory.pod.debug:layout/activity_home: Binary XML file line #8 in com.memory.pod.debug:layout/activity_home: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.memory.pod.debug:layout/activity_home: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
     Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.arindam.camerax.ui.home.permission.PermissionsFragment: make sure class name exists
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentFactory.loadFragmentClass(FragmentFactory.java:91)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:546)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate(FragmentManager.java:390)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.instantiateFragment(FragmentNavigator.java:132)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:162)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:58)
        at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.java:71)
        at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.java:28)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:935)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated(NavController.java:577)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:534)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:499)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:481)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:237)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2684)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:280)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1175)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1818)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.<init>(FragmentContainerView.java:166)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:51)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:335)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1069)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.memory.pod.camerax.ui.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:11)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7825)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7814)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.arindam.camerax.ui.home.permission.PermissionsFragment
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentFactory.loadClass(FragmentFactory.java:47)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentFactory.loadFragmentClass(FragmentFactory.java:88)
            ... 53 more
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.arindam.camerax.ui.home.permission.PermissionsFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.memory.pod.debug-koXsvzgNs8unWof_uGUUgw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.memory.pod.debug-koXsvzgNs8unWof_uGUUgw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
```

Side not the hyperlink highlighted section is

```
com.memory.pod.camerax.ui.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:11)
```

Comment: It could be even simplified to: `provideLayout()?.let(::setContentView)` i.e. passing reference of the function that can be callable instead of creating new lambda expression and then calling setContentView from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is "it" a variable?

`it` is a parameter passed into the lambda expression.

Taking this piece by piece...

- `provideLayout()` is a function, returning an object.
- `?.` is a "safe call", meaning that if the object is `null`, we skip the call
- `?.let()` is a particular usage of a safe call that says "execute this lambda expression if the object is not `null`, and pass that object in as a parameter; if the object is `null`, though, skip it and let's just go have lunch"
- `{ setContentView(it) }` is a lambda expression that is called by `let()` if the object returned by `provideLayout()` is not `null`, and that object is referred to in the lambda expression as `it` (where `it` is the default name of the lambda parameter, since we did not provide another name)

If we knew that `provideLayout()` would never return `null`, or if `setContentView()` could support `null`, this could be simplified as:

```
setContentView(provideLayout())
```

Comment: Wow! Awesome answer, thank you very much. I'll give it the check mark, but just wanted  a bit of clarification one point. I imported the project and am trying to run it, however it seems to fail at the provideLayout()?.let { setContentView(it) }. When I hover over the "it" with my mouse android studio mentiones the following. "automatically declared based on the expected type". Would you possibly know why this is? Why would the it crash at this point? I have updated my code with the error

Comment: @Joe: Your crash is related to a class that Android cannot find: `com.arindam.camerax.ui.home.permission.PermissionsFragment`. If you just checked out the project and did not change it, it might be a bug in the project.